# Is there a way to edit NIfTI images to delete slices?

Tags: png, nifti

A lot of the medical images we have consist of black images. I tried to eliminate them by converting the [NIfTI](https://radiopaedia.org/articles/nifti-file-format) files to a series of PNGs, deleting the PNGs and converting back. Does anybody know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with SimpleITK, but are you replacing the black images with something else?  Or are you just squishing the remaining images together?  That's going to mess up the 3d positions of the 2d slices.

If you want to just take out a black slice and collapse the remaining slices, you'd do something like this:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

img = sitk.ReadImage("your_3d_image.nii")

slices = []

# Extract the Z slices into a list
for i in img.GetDepth():
    slices.append(img[i])

# Remove whichever slices you don't like
slices.remove(42)

# Create a new 3d image by joining together the remaining slices
new_img = sitk.JoinSeries(slices)

sitk.WriteImage(new_img, "your_new_3d_image.nii")
```

Comment: yes indeed, just taking out a slice without accounting for the effect on image-to-world mapping can get you in all kinds of trouble...

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to take out a slice in python/matlab:

```
import nibabel as nb;
import numpy as np;
img    = nb.load ( "MNI152_T1_2mm_brain_mask.nii.gz" );
imgvol = np.array ( img.dataobj );
imgvol = imgvol [ :, :, 1:90 ]; # remove 1st and last
newimg = nb.Nifti1Image ( imgvol, img.affine );
newimg.to_filename ( "/tmp/newimg.nii.gz" );
```

or something similar, but (assuming that you're acquiring 3D scans and that each slice corresponds to a position): this effectively moves all slice above the one(s) you remove, down by 1 slice position each.

This has an effect that you can see straight away in the (better) viewer: the origin of the coordinate system (given by the Q and S forms), is now in a different, higher point in the image.

I don't think that is what you want? Otherwise this is all there is to it.